# Replace the word ROAD with RD

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below mentioned code whenever I am replacing the word ROAD with RD., then word BROAD is also getting replaced to BRD.

```
def subst(pattern, replace_str, string):
    #new_string = [word.replace(pattern,replace_str) for word in string]
    new_string=[]
    for word in string:
        if re.match(pattern, word):
            new_string.append(word.replace(pattern,replace_str))
        else:
            new_string.append(word)
    #susbstitute pattern and return it
    return new_string


def main():
    addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
            '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
            'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']

    #Create pattern Implementation here 

    #Use subst function to replace 'ROAD' to 'RD.',Store as new_address
    new_address= subst('ROAD','RD.',addr)
    return new_address
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  For future reference, to post code, paste it in, select it, and click the `{}` widget, which shifts it right 4 spaces causing it to be rendered as code.  Avoid tabs unless they're 4 spaces.

Comment: try `subst(r'\bROAD\b','RD.',addr)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: words aren't always separated by spaces.  For example, "spaces" in my previous sentence.

Comment: word boundary doesn't rely on spaces. It relies on non-letters/non-digits/non-underscore/start or end of string.

Comment: There are other bugs here.  First, the code reads as though it's looping through words, but it's looping through lines.  Second, `re.match()` matches an initial substring, not anywhere (I think you need `re.search()`.)  Third, string `replace` won't match regular expressions.  Try `re.sub()`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks, my mistake!

Comment: Thanks....got the solution